# Vue.js Passing Button Parameters to Veux Store

Tags: vue.js, vuex

While I'm able to Fetch Data, using Vuex Mapstate, and pass a Value from my Search Field into Vuex, the issue I'm currently facing is when I'm trying to pass Parameters from a Button into Vuex in order to Post Data to the Backend API application, While having the POST axois function in the method section of the vue.js page works, I would like to move this into my Store index.js so other elements on different pages can call on this as Store function.

Vue Page

```
<template>
  <div class="container" style=" padding-top: 50px;">
     <!-- Bootswatch -->
 
    <div class="row my-5 card-wrapper">
      
      <div
            class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4"
            v-for="(vdesk, index) in vdesks"
            :key="index">

        <div class="card h-200">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                <!-- Display Image -->
                <template v-if="vdesk.MachineOpt == 'Windows'">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <img v-bind:src="require('@/assets/windows.png')" />
                    </div>
                </template>
                <template v-if="vdesk.MachineOpt == 'Ubuntu'">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <img v-bind:src="require('@/assets/linux.png')" />
                    </div>
                </template>

          <div class="card-body">
                <!-- Display vDesk Machine Name -->
                <h4 class="card-title">
                    vDesk: {{ vdesk.MachineName }}
                </h4>
              <!-- Display vDesk Status -->
              <p class="card-text">Machine State: {{ vdesk.MachineStatus }}</p>

              <!-- Action Buttons -->
              <template v-if="vdesk.MachineStatus != 'Powered Off' && vdesk.MachineStatus != 'Running Job'">
                <button type="button" 
                        :v-model="TitleDesk"
                        class="btn btn-outline-warning"
                        :value="({'vSphere':'Horizon','PowerCycle':'PowerOff', 'vDesk':vdesk})"
                        @click="SubmitPowerCycle({'vSphere':'Horizon','PowerCycle':'PowerOff', 'vDesk':vdesk})">
                        <i class="fas fa-power-off"></i></button>

                 <button type="button" 
                         class="btn btn-outline-primary" 
                         @click="SubmitPowerCycle({'vSphere':'Horizon','PowerCycle':'Restart', 'vDesk':vdesk})">
                         <i class="fas fa-recycle"></i></button>

                 <button type="button" 
                         class="btn btn-outline-danger"
                         @click="SubmitPowerCycle({'vSphere':'Horizon','PowerCycle':'Delete', 'vDesk':vdesk})">
                         <i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>
  
              <template v-if="vdesk.MachineOpt == 'Windows'">
                   <button type="button"
                           class="btn btn-outline-info">
                           <i class="fas fa-desktop"></i></button>
              </template>
              </template>

              <template v-if="vdesk.MachineStatus == 'Powered Off'">
                <button type="button" 
                         class="btn btn-outline-danger"
                         @click="SubmitPowerCycle({'vSphere':'Horizon','PowerCycle':'Delete', 'vDesk':vdesk})">
                         <i class="fas fa-power-off"></i></button>
      
                <button type="button" 
                         class="btn btn-outline-danger"
                         @click="SubmitPowerCycle({'vSphere':'Horizon','PowerCycle':'Delete', 'vDesk':vdesk})">
                         <i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>
              </template>

              <template v-if="vdesk.MachineStatus == 'Running Job'">
                <Spinner />
              </template>
              
                <!-- Footer -->
               <div class="card-footer" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                 <small small-class="text-muted" >
                   Desktop Pool: {{ vdesk.vPool }}
                 </small>
                 <br>
                   <small small-class="text-muted" >
                   Horizon Server: {{ vdesk.vCenter }}
                 </small>
               </div>
              </div>
        </div>
      </div>
          <!-- End of Card --> 
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

//TO-DO Move SubmitPowerCycle to VUEX 
import Spinner from '@/components/Spinner.vue';
import {mapState} from 'vuex';

export default {
props: {

},

data() {
    return {
      polling: null,  
    };
    },

message: '',



computed:{
  ...mapState(['vdesks']),

TitleDesk:{
  get() {
      return this.$store.getters.TitleDesk;
  },
  set(TitleDesk) {
    this.$store.commit('Click', TitleDesk)
  }
}
},

components: {
    Spinner
},


methods: {
   SubmitPowerCycle(){
     this.$store.dispatch('PowerCycle', this.payload);
   },


  pollData () {
    this.polling = setInterval (() => {
      this.$store.dispatch("FeatchvDesks")
    }, 12000)
  }
},

beforeUnmount() {
  clearInterval(this.polling)
},

created() {
    this.$store.dispatch("FeatchvDesks")
    this.pollData()
  },
};
</script>
```

Vuex

```
    import { createStore } from "vuex";
import axios from "axios"


export default createStore({
  state: {
    vdesks: [],
    SearchvDesks: [],
    PostTitle: '',
    Click: []
  },
  
  getter: {
    TitleUser: state => {
      return state.PostTitle;
    },
    vdesk: state => {
      return state.PostTitlevDesk;
    },
    TitleDesk: state => {
      return state.Click;
    }
  },
  
  mutations: {
  SET_VDESKS(state, payload){
    state.vdesks = payload;
  },

  SET_USERVDESKS(state, payload){
    state.SearchvDesks = payload;
},

  PostTitle(state, payload) {
    state.PostTitle = payload;
 },
 Click(state ,payload) {
    state.Click = payload
 }
},

  actions: {
    FeatchvDesks({commit}){
      const path = 'http://localhost:5000/horizon';
      axios.get(path)
      .then((res) => {
          (commit("SET_VDESKS", res.data.vdesks))
      })
      .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error)
      });
  },

  FetchUservDesks({commit, state}) {
    const path = 'http://localhost:5000/searchdata';
    axios.post(path, {
      TitleUser: state.PostTitle
  })
    .then((res) => {
        (commit("SET_USERVDESKS", res.data.SearchvDesks))  
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
  },

  SubmitPowerCycle({commit,state}){
    const path = 'http://localhost:5000/horizon';
    axios.post(path,state.Click)
    .then((res) =>{ 
      (commit("Click", res.data.SearchvDesks))  
    })
    .cath((error)=>{
      console.error(error);
    });
  }

},
  modules: {},
});
```

Comment: You should have a services layer and call the service from your action. You can see an example here: https://github.com/gothinkster/vue-realworld-example-app/blob/master/src/store/article.module.js#L53

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly you want to have a POST api call that can be used by any of your vue.js components.

This could be best acheived by using a Vuex action, and then mapping that action using `mapActions`

in your vuex file:

```
...
actions: {
  async postData({state}, data) {
    const result = await axios.post('//your/endpoint', data);
    return result
  }
}
```

In your vue component:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="postData('data to post')">Post</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import { mapActions } from 'vuex'
  export default {
    methods: {
      ...mapActions(['postData'])
    }
  }
  
  </script>
```

Comment: Thanks, it appears that MapActions worked, vs using Setters / Getters and calling the Vuex function my $store.dispatch()